# Django not null constraint failed when form is submitted

Tags: django, model

I use the basic user model, and i'd like to have a profile connected to it aswell. But when I submit my form i get this error: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
goal = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from users import models
from users.models import Profile
from .forms import WeightForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form = WeightForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WeightForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()
   return render(request, 'Landing/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "update" case is running before the create case. Instead of having two receivers, use one with a condition on `created`.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
       instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting the same error. The strange part is that that I can see the profile on my admin page but, the error occurs if i want to submit data inside the form